# No module named 'mplsoccer'

Tags: python, ubuntu, module

I have install a module named "mplsoccer" in my Ubuntu to work on soccer visualization. But everytime I run, it shows: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mplsoccer'.

I ran my code on Visual Studio Code. I also tried PyCharm. In Pycharm, in the project interpreter section it shows the 'mplsoccer' package same as it shows 'pandas'. But still I can't find a solution.

Comment: Can run on Python3.6 or later.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a package manager and virtual environment to install your packages. This ensures that all your packages are installed in one place and there are no dependency issues.

For example, using [miniconda3](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) and assuming it is installed already. mplsoccer is available via conda-forge which you can check by searching for packages here: https://anaconda.org/search?q=mplsoccer

1. `conda create --name <name_of_env> python=<version_#>` (version_# must be > 3.6 for mplsoccer)
2. `conda activate <name_of_env>`
3. `conda install -c conda-forge mplsoccer`
4. Run your python file

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps:

```bash
# Create a virtual env
conda create -n myconda python=3.7
conda activate myconda

# install pip using conda
conda install pip

# install mplsoccer using pip
pip install mplsoccer
```

Then try:

```py
import mplsoccer
```